# Deploying AWS chatbot without the use of the S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

Im trying to integrate an AWS chatbot to my Website with the help from this github repository https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui , and im trying to get this deployed completely locally which means the S3 bucket will not be used, only the "cognito id" will be used,is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Normally if someone asks "is this possible?", they will hear "try it first, then ask if there's a problem" but since you're new, I figured I would point you in the right direction with my answer. If you run into any problems integrating that, feel free to ask a new question with all the details of what you tried. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JayA.Little, i've tried that but i'm getting CORS error trying to retrieve the lex-web-ui-loader.js and  i tried various methods but i keep getting this error "access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/lex-web-ui-loader-config.json' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.", So im currently unsure if its the lex bot or my local website that's restricting the access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Take a look at the [methods of integration](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui#integrating-into-your-site-and-deploying):

[image]

Only Method 1 uses S3 Bucket. You probably want method 3 to create a stand-alone page or an embedded iframe. Here are the links to those directions:

[Stand-alone Page](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui#stand-alone-page)

[Embeddable iframe](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui#iframe)

Note that method 3 says to use the libraries from the **dist** folder. That is commonly overlooked.